# How does one find the currency value in a string?

Tags: python, regex, currency

I'm writing a small tool to extract a bunch of values from a string (usually a tweet).

The string could consist of words and numbers along with an amount prefixed by a currency symbol (£,$,€ etc.) and a number of hashtags (#foo #bar). I'm running on appEngine and using tweepy to bring in the tweets.

The current code I have to find the values is below:

```
tagex = re.compile(r'#.*')
curex = re.compile(ur'[£].*')
for x in api.user_timeline(since_id = t.lastimport):
          tags = re.findall(tagex, x.text)
          amount = re.findall(curex, x.text)[0]
          logging.info("Text: " + x.text)
          logging.info("Tags: " + str(tags))
          logging.info("Amount: " + amount)
```

where x.text is for example "Taxi London £6.50 #projectfoo #clientmeeting"

The tagex finds the hashtags fine, but I can't get curex to extract the amount currently I get:
Amount: £6.50 #projectfoo #clientmeeting.

I also need to separate off the currency symbol so as to get the amount as a float, but that should be pretty simple later.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
>>> re.search(ur'([£$€])(\d+(?:\.\d{2})?)', s).groups()
(u'\xa3', u'6.50')
```

- `[£$€]` matches one currency symbol
- `\d+(?:\.\d{2})` matches one or more digits followed by an optional decimal point followed by exactly two digits
- The `()`'s capture the symbol and amount separately

The problem with your regex is that `.*` matches anything and is greedy, so at the end of a regex it matches everything that follows.

Comment: awesome thanks :-) Also found I needed to add # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
to the top of my file but I guess thats just good practice?

Comment: @Sam 2.x requires it, but 3.x defaults to utf-8. I'd only add the header if its required like in this case.

Comment: For some reason this gives me a syntax error, unless I remove the `u` prefix before the string.

Answer (score 2):

I've altered Marcog's regex altered a bit

```
    re.search(ur'([£\$€])(\d+(?:\.\d{2})?)', s).groups()
```

by escaping the dollar sign.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with installing an additional python package named [`price-parser`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/price-parser), then you can try the following:

Install the package

```
python -m pip install price-parser
```

Code to get the currency and amount

```py
from price_parser import Price
result = Price.fromstring("Taxi London £6.50 #projectfoo #clientmeeting")
print(result)
```

Output:

```
Price(amount=Decimal('6.50'), currency='£')
```