# Replace bn with Billion, Mn with Million using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a sentence:

```
Input1: "Deal to invest $1000 mn in market." 
Input2: "Deal to invest $1000mn in market."
Input3: "Deal to invest $ 1000mn in market."
```

Every such occurrences of mn,bn, $ should be replaced by full name:

```
Expected Output:  "Deal to invest 1000 Million Dollar in market."
```

I have tried answer in this link:
     [How does one find the currency value in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862827/how-does-one-find-the-currency-value-in-a-string)

Comment: Rahul, why don't u take a second and see the link I tried. It's so easy to put -1. Disappointing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take help of dictionary:

```
import re

mbt_d = {
    "mn": "Million",
    "bn": "Billion",
    "tn": "Trillion",
    #include your needs.
}

dol_d = {
    "$": "dollar",
    #include your needs.
}

inputs = [
    "Deal to invest $1000 mn in market.",
    "Deal to invest $10bn in market.",
    "Deal to invest $ 1tn in market."
]

for s in inputs:
    res = re.findall(r"([£$€]\s?)(\d+)(\s?[mbt]n)", s)[0]
    s = s.replace(res[0], "")
    print(s.replace(
        res[2], " {} {}".format(mbt_d[res[2].strip()], dol_d[res[0].strip()])
    ))

out: Deal to invest 1000 Million dollar in market.
     Deal to invest 1000 Billion dollar in market.
     Deal to invest 1000 Trillion dollar in market.
```

Comment: Might want to check for whitespace after `[mbt]n` too!

Comment: and `\w+` after that, and again white space after that.