# Redact a JSON response using Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-cognitive-services, text-recognition, redaction

I am using Cognitive Read API to extract the text from an image. I am getting the response as below:

```
{
  "status": "Succeeded",
  "recognitionResult": {
    "lines": [
      {
        "boundingBox": [
          2,
          52,
          65,
          46,
          69,
          89,
          7,
          95
        ],
        "text": "$230",
        "words": [
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              0,
              59,
              63,
              43,
              77,
              86,
              3,
              102
            ],
            "text": "$230"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "boundingBox": [
          6,
          2,
          771,
          13,
          770,
          75,
          5,
          64
        ],
        "text": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy",
        "words": [
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              0,
              4,
              92,
              5,
              77,
              71,
              0,
              71
            ],
            "text": "The"
          },
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              74,
              4,
              189,
              5,
              174,
              72,
              60,
              71
            ],
            "text": "quick"
          },
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              176,
              5,
              321,
              6,
              306,
              73,
              161,
              72
            ],
            "text": "brown"
          },
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              308,
              6,
              387,
              6,
              372,
              73,
              293,
              73
            ],
            "text": "fox"
          },
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              382,
              6,
              506,
              7,
              491,
              74,
              368,
              73
            ],
            "text": "jumps"
          },
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              492,
              7,
              607,
              8,
              592,
              75,
              478,
              74
            ],
            "text": "over"
          },
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              589,
              8,
              673,
              8,
              658,
              75,
              575,
              75
            ],
            "text": "the"
          },
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              660,
              8,
              783,
              9,
              768,
              76,
              645,
              75
            ],
            "text": "lazy"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "boundingBox": [
          2,
          84,
          783,
          96,
          782,
          154,
          1,
          148
        ],
        "text": "$78,000.00",
        "words": [
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              0,
              86,
              94,
              87,
              72,
              151,
              0,
              149
            ],
            "text": "$78,000.00"
          },
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              76,
              87,
              164,
              88,
              142,
              152,
              54,
              150
            ],
            "text": "my"
          },
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              155,
              88,
              243,
              89,
              222,
              152,
              134,
              151
            ],
            "text": "box"
          },
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              226,
              89,
              344,
              90,
              323,
              154,
              204,
              152
            ],
            "text": "with"
          },
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              336,
              90,
              432,
              91,
              411,
              154,
              314,
              154
            ],
            "text": "five"
          },
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              419,
              91,
              538,
              92,
              516,
              154,
              398,
              154
            ],
            "text": "dozen"
          },
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              547,
              92,
              701,
              94,
              679,
              154,
              525,
              154
            ],
            "text": "liquor"
          },
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              696,
              94,
              800,
              95,
              780,
              154,
              675,
              154
            ],
            "text": "jugs"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now my requirement is to mask all the amounts($230,$78,000.00) in the Json response with XXXXX or black out those numbers.
I am using azure notebooks to build the code in python 3.6. 
Please help if anyone worked on this earlier.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the JSON response, but you can control what you show to your users from the response!

You can check for each text returned if it includes the `$` character and remove everything that comes after it!

Here's an example:

```
text = 'some text$ this part will be removed.'
head, sep, tail = text.partition('$')
```

`print(head)` will show "some text"

`print(sep)` will show "$"

`print(tail)` will show " this part will be removed."

Comment: Maybe using a regular expression like in this post may be better for detection and replacement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862827/how-does-one-find-the-currency-value-in-a-string